# How to emboss sharp shapes into a sphere?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel, boolean-modifier

I'm using blender v3.1. I want to embed/emboss emoticon faces onto spheres to look like this. So far I have been able to boolean the face into the sphere but have not been able to achieve the soft/bevelled upper edges. I can't seem to find a way to bevel the edges to this extent.
Does anyone know how I should go about achieving this effect?

[image]

Comment: do you have to model it? don't you want to do it with bump or normal map?

Comment: I would like it to be modelled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane, rotate 90° on X, subdivide it (16x16 more or less), put the origin at its right edge, give it a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 180° on X:

[image]

Give it a second *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 360° on Z:

[image]

Disable the 2 *Simple Deform* modifiers, model this kind of topology:

[image]

Reactivate the modifiers, smooth, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps alot.